# Apex Oracle print on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, css, oracle, media, oracle-apex

I have a page that contains 2 interactive report.
I need to print it so I have a javascript function that calls window.print()

So I've put some CSS to adjust my table

```
@media print {
 width: 100%; 
 height: 100%; 
 margin: 0% 0% 0% 0%; 
}
```

The problem is running this page on IE 8 (or prior), because @media
isn't supported.

How can I print these files?

I've put the same CSS into an external file and call it

```
<link href="print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" type="text/css" />
```

but it doesn't work

How can I solve it?

Thank you

Comment: Add/remove the extra stylings 'manually' when the page gets printed on <=IE8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I think ou should use 'conditional stylesheets'.

You can create a `css` file like `IEPrint.css` and put the specific styles you want there, and with your other stylesheets you put something like this:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="IEPrint.css">
<![endif]-->
```

The code above will only 'work' if the user is in Internet Explorer 8.

You can use other conditionals like:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

The code above 'works' for Internet Explorer 8 and Lower.

Here is a great article about stylesheets conditionals: https://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

---

### Trigger print style on click For Internet Explorer with jQuery

But to control the element style when another element click event is triggered, we should use javascript *(this is not the best way)*.

I did a fiddle so you can see the code in action: https://jsfiddle.net/dobbinx3/pLvzk8rv/6/

Basically we have an element `<p>` that when we want to print it turns red, when we are not printing it, the color is black.

A `button` that has a click event triggered on it.

And a function to restore the screen layout when we finish the print action.

**REMEMBER**

1. You should do this 'workaround' only for Internet Explorer, put an `<script>` inside the conditional I mentioned before and use it only for the browsers that did not support @media print.
2. I noticed that you will set the `height` to 100%, check the `display`, and if you want the `position` attributes. If you think it is not working. For example if you want to set it in a `<div>` element.

Hope it works,

Cya.

Comment: Hi, how can I 'use' these css just when calling window.print

Comment: Well in this case, we should try to handle this adding an class via javascript. What are you using? jQuery, angular, 'pure' javascript?

Comment: I did an example with jQuery, I will edit my answer so you can visualize better.

Comment: Thank you very much, I got some tips from this ;)